# PHP: WSDL Request - missing required parameter 'document'

Tags: php, soap, xmlhttprequest, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to connect to the WSDL and making a call for "Query_ByExample". See the example below.

I have tried multiple options but unfortunately I was not able to create a request.

```
$username="xxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxx";


$soapURL = "";

$client = new SoapClient($soapURL, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0, "login" => $username, "password" => $password) );



$params = array(
        'TypeElpProcess' => array(            
            'user' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'name' => 'QUERY_BY_EXAMPLE'
            ),            
        'TypeOrderDetails' => array(
            'RMANo' => '123123'
        )

);


var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$response = $client->BookingElpEntry($params);


echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

The error message is:

```
   An Exception was thrown in the server:java.lang.Exception: missing required parameter 'document'
        [faultcode] => soapenv:Server
```

What do I need to do to accomplish a succesful request? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all.